# Pass object name into do.call() function

Tags: r, do.call

Is there a way to pass object name into do.call() function?

For example:

```
#First make a function that will return the name of object itself.
PrintObjectName <- function(obj){
  print(deparse(substitute(obj)))
}

data(iris)

PrintObjectName(iris)
[1] "iris" #This is what I want

do.call(what="PrintObjectName", args=list(obj=iris))
#The output is a messy stuff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `alist` within your call to `do.call`.

`alist` handles its arguments as if they described function arguments. So the values are not evaluated

```
do.call(what="PrintObjectName", args=alist(obj=iris))
# [1] "iris"
```

or you could use `quote`

```
do.call(what="PrintObjectName", args=list(obj=quote(iris)))
```

Comment: I think at this point you're better off switching to using `eval()` and manually constructing calls.